# Load file from "Resource Files" folder C++ Windows Application (win32)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to load a file from the `Resource Files` folder inside my Windows Application (Win32) C++.

My folder structure inside Visual Studios is as following:

- External Dependencies folder
- Header Files folder
- Resource Files Folder

  - Web Folder

    - css folder
    - js folder
    - images folder
    - login.html

The only way i've been able to access the `login.html` file is by doing the following:

```
WebBrowser->Navigate("file://C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\WindowsProject\\Windows\\MIA_Windows\\MIA_Windows\\MIA_Windows\\web\\login.html");
```

I don't want to access it by doing the whole path. I want to be able to access it like the following:

```
WebBrowser->Navigate("file://\\web\\login.html");
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I'd be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native resources can be loaded from embedded resources using the `res://` URL scheme.

See [the MSDN documentation for the `res:` protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [more details from the Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/220830)

For non-embedded content, you can try setting the `BaseURL` for the host WebBrowser, which controls decoding of relative URLs.

Comment: Where does the path of `res:` start?

Comment: @Chris: From [KB 220830](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/220830): "You do not have to specify the whole path to the module, on the condition that the module is either in the path or is a loaded DLL."